# Is it possible to activate a strategy function with a bool input?

Tags: bots, trading, tradingview-api

I'm working on a strategy and I struggle on some lines. I would like to know if it is possible to have a bool input to be able to activate a strategy function ?

The purpose is to be able to choose to activate or not a max drawdown risk strategy via the strategy.risk.max_drawdown function, with a certain percentage of total equity.

So it would go like this :

1. You tick the option and now the strategy is automatically closing all open trades when reaching max drawdown
2. You don't tick the option and you have unlimited drawdown

I've searched the whole documentation (both on tradingview and tradingcode) but I can't find how i can link the bool input to the strategy..

I tried something like this but of course it doesnt work^^

```
// Stop trading after losing more than 4.9 percents of total equity

myinput = input.bool(true, title="5% Max Drawdown", tooltip="Activate 5% Max Drawdown")

if (myinput != "true")
    strategy.risk.max_drawdown(value=4.9, type=strategy.percent_of_equity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a [ternary](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_?:) in *value*

something like this:

```
myinput = input.bool(true, title="5% Max Drawdown", tooltip="Activate 5% Max Drawdown")

strategy.risk.max_drawdown(value = myinput ? 4.9 : 100, type=strategy.percent_of_equity)
```